# python & db async requests (aka fire-and-forget): how to?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

in the middle of a function I'd like to be able to fire off a call to the DB (burn results) but the function keeps on running so that I do not experience an **I/O bottleneck**. this is **NOT** a web application. all is offline.

snippet for *explanatory* purposes:

```
a = list(range(100))
for i in a:
    my_output = very_long_function(i)
    # I'd like to_sql to run in a "fire-and-forget fashion"
    function_of_choice_to_sql(my_output)
```

I was wondering whether I was better off with the **threading** library, **asyncio** or other tools. I was unsuccessful in this particular endeavour with none of them. i'll take any working solution.

any help?

**p.s.:** there will like be no problems with **concurrency/locking** and the like since in my case the time my function takes to compute is far larger than the time for the database to be written.

Comment: You can use to accomplish this background  task using celery if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor), it provides a simple interface to schedule callables to a pool of worker. In particular, you might be interested in the [map](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) method:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    # Lazy map (python3 only)
    outputs = map(very_long_function, range(10)) 
    # Asynchronous map
    results = executor.map(function_of_choice_to_sql, outputs)
    # Wait for the results
    print(list(results))
```